# R use purrr::map to apply a function on a selected columns in a dataframe list

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

I have a list of dataframes, where some columns need specification of their correct  encoding. So, I have created a function to set the correct encoding, and I would like to apply this new function to the specific columns in my dataframes list. How can I do this with `purrr:map`? I am very new to it.

---

Dummy example

```
# Set slovak characters
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Slovak")


# Make a function    
setEncoding<- function(x, ...) {
    Encoding(x)<-"UTF-8"  # set correct encoding on the vector
    x                     # print the output
}

# Create dummy data with wrong encoding
df1<-data.frame(name = "Ä˝ubietovskĂ˝ Vepor",
                psb = "S CHKO PoÄľana",
                numb = 1)

df2<-data.frame(name = "GoliaĹˇovĂˇ",
                psb = "S TANAP",
                numb = 2)

list1<-list(df1, df2)

My function seems working if applied on vector string:

>setEncoding(c("Ä˝ubietovskĂ˝ Vepor", "GoliaĹˇovĂˇ" ))
[1] "Ľubietovský Vepor" "Goliašová"  

# How to apply the whatever function (here setEncoding) on the selected columns from a dataframe list?? 

list1 %>%
  map(setEncoding[c("name", "psb")]) # How to fix this?
```

---

What I wish to obtain (correct encoding of columns `name`, `psb`):

```
> ls
[[1]]
         name            psb numb
1 Ľubietovský Vepor S CHKO Poľana    1

[[2]]
         name     psb numb
1 Goliášová S TANAP    2
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details with encoding for your desired result, but I can answer the question regarding using `purrr`. You can use `map_if` to only apply the function to `character` vectors (since `Encoding()` expects a `character` input). Also your example data frames contain factors not strings.

```
library(purrr)
df1<-data.frame(name = "Ä˝ubietovskĂ˝ Vepor",
                psb = "S CHKO PoÄľana",
                numb = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2<-data.frame(name = "GoliaĹˇovĂˇ",
                psb = "S TANAP",
                numb = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

list1 <- list(df1, df2) #using ls conflicts with ls() function

list1 %>% 
  map_if(is.character, setEncoding) #this only maps on 'name' and 'pbs'
```

Comment: Thank you for conversion of factor to strings and correction of list. But, how can I specify only the selected columns? Also, does the output work for you? For me, the `map_if(is.character, setEncoding)` does not produce expected outputs...

Comment: if you want to specify the columns by name you can use `list1 %>% map_at(c("name", "pbs"), setEncoding)` what does your output look like using `map_if`?

Comment: My output using map_if look like the function have not been applied:  `[[1]]
                 name            psb numb
1 Ä˝ubietovskĂ˝ Vepor S CHKO PoÄľana    1

[[2]]
         name     psb numb
1 GoliaĹˇovĂˇ S TANAP    2` and `list1 %>% map_at(c("name", "pbs"), setEncoding)` reports error `Error: character indexing requires a named object`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't fully understand the details with encoding so it might have to do something with your language locales that I can't reproduce with own machine